# Using a Custom React based Modal, how can I pass a dynamic triggering function so I can re-use the component?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-modal, react-props, react-functional-component, bootstrap-styled

I have the following component which makes up my modal:

```
import React from 'react';
import { ModalBody, Button, Alert } from 'bootstrap';
import { AppModalHeader } from '../../common/AppModalHeader';
import ModalWrapper from './ModalWrapper';

const QuestionModal= ({
    title,
    noText = 'No',
    yesText = 'Yes',
    questionText,
    onYesAction
    children
}) => {
    const { toggle, isOpen, openModal } = useModalForm();
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <ModalWrapper className={className} isOpen={isOpen} toggle={toggle}>
                <AppModalHeader toggle={toggle}>{modalTitle}</AppModalHeader>
                {isOpen ? (
                    <ModalBody>
                        <p>{questionText}</p>
                        <Button
                            className="float-right"
                            color="primary"
                            onClick={() => {
                                if (onYesAction !== undefined) {
                                    onYesAction(toggle);
                                }
                            }}
                        >
                            {yesText != null ? yesText : 'Yes'}
                        </Button>
                    </ModalBody>
                ) : null}
            </ModalWrapper>
            {children({
                triggerModal: () => openModal({ id: undefined }),
                toggle
            })}
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};

export default QuestionModal;
```

I want to use it as such, where I can dynamically choose the name of the trigger that opens the modal:

In use e.g. (note: the inner question modal would be repeated, used 4 or 5 times in my application):

```
....
<QuestionModal
     //....params that match up with above
    >
    {({ triggerModal }) => (
    <QuestionModal
         //....params that match up with the component
    >
        {({ triggerModal2 }) => (
        <>
           <Button onClick={()=>triggerModal();}>Trigger Modal 1</Button>
           <div>
               <Button onClick={()=>triggerModal2();}>Trigger Modal 2</Button>
           </div>
        </>
    </>
    )}
</QuestionModal>
....
```

How could I achieve this, by extending the question modal to pass a dynamic function? Just because I keep getting stuck in having to think about duplicating the original component, I want to make this component as reusable as I can. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think you're overcomplicating things. The problem is you're trying to control whether or not the modal is rendered from *inside* the modal itself. If you really want to have reusable components, it's good to decouple **presentation** from **logic**. In your case, you want to have a modal component with all the presentation/layout/styling stuff and pass in via props the actual content.

For example:

```
import React from 'react';
import { ModalBody, Button, Alert } from 'bootstrap';
import { AppModalHeader } from '../../common/AppModalHeader';
import ModalWrapper from './ModalWrapper';

const QuestionModal= ({
    title,
    noText = 'No',
    yesText = 'Yes',
    questionText,
    onYesAction
    children
}) => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <ModalWrapper>
                <AppModalHeader toggle={toggle}>{title}</AppModalHeader>
                    <ModalBody>
                        <p>{questionText}</p>
                        <Button
                            className="float-right"
                            color="primary"
                            onClick={onYesAction}
                        >
                            {yesText}
                        </Button>
                    </ModalBody>
            </ModalWrapper>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};

export default QuestionModal;
```

Now this is a purely presentational component, it creates a skeleton in which you put the actual content. And for using it, you'll control whether or not the modal is rendered from where it is actually used, like so:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import QuestionModal from './QuestionModal'

const SomeComponent = (props) => {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

  const toggleModal = () => {
    setShowModal(!showModal);
  }

  const yesActionLogic = () => {
    // Your yes-action logic...
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {showModal ? (
        <QuestionModal
          title="Sample title",
          questionText="Question?"
          onYesAction={yesActionLogic}
        />
      ) : null}

      <Button onClick={toggleModal}>Toggle Modal</Button>

      {/* The rest of your stuff... */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you want to create reusable components, it's good practice to not put any business logic on it. Use props to pass in functions that will be triggered from inside the components, and lift all the work to the components that actually hold your business logic.

One of the [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) principles of software engineering is called Single-responsibility principle, and you can apply it to your React components:

- Your Modal component is responsible for displaying data in its correct layout and triggering some set of functions from outside, regardless of what data/logic you pass.
- This Modal component will be used by some other component whose responsibility is to show the user a modal with some **specific data**, at the **right time**.

So it makes sense that you should toggle your modal from outside.

On a personal note, I like to structure a React app in *components* that hold only presentational logic, and are used by *containers*, which are more logic-dense (generally having async requests).